# ImportError: cannot import name AccessMixin

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run the following package from github - `https://github.com/rollstudio/django-admin2-sb`

But I'm getting the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djadmin2/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djadmin2/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import apiviews
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djadmin2/apiviews.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .viewmixins import Admin2Mixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djadmin2/viewmixins.py", line 15, in <module>
    from braces.views import AccessMixin
ImportError: cannot import name AccessMixin
```

braces is installed I can see it in the following location -

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/braces/views`

`_access.py` contains the class `class AccessMixin(object):`

so why doesn't it import?

Comment: try `import braces` and `print braces.__file__` check it is picking from sitepackages

Comment: @itzmeontv the print returns this `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/braces/__init__.py`

Comment: is `braces` contains views.py ?

Comment: no the structure is that there's a folder called views and in there the AccessMixin is in a file called _access.py so like this - `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/braces/views/_access.py`

Comment: lol.  they're the ones that are requiring braces.  k I'll dig further and see if I can get some help from the developer :)

Answer (score 1):

In **django-braces 1.3**, views exported `AccessMixin` but in **django-braces 1.4** this was moved  to `views._access` and not exported in views.
This should be fixed in versions>1.4

Another workaround for this error is to downgrade django-braces to **version 1.3.1.**

Checkout this github issue:  https://github.com/pydanny/django-admin2/issues/396